# How to use Teradata structured UDT

Tags: sql, transform, teradata, user-defined-types

I have to create a structured User Defined Type and use it as routine's parameters datatype in Teradata.

So I've created the following UDT

```
create type sysudtlib.person as(ssn character(11),first_name varchar(20)) not final;
```

However, wherever I try to use the created UDT, either in table DDL or in stored procedure

```
create table twm_source.test_udt(purchase_id int, customer sysudtlib.person);

create procedure twm_source.sp_test_udt(in p1 sysudtlib.person)
begin
insert into tbl_udt values(p1.ssn, p1.first_name);
end;
```

I get the same error:

```
User-defined  Transform is not defined for UDT 'person' .
```

It looks like I have to add a definition of the UDT-GroupName to the DBC.UDTTRANSFORM dictionary table.
Could anyone please provide some brief but vivid example of code that illustrates how to do so. Just something I need to do in order to get my structured UDT ready for use.

Any help is greatly appreciated.